# Mysql Failover (Unable to write operations to new master)

Tags: mysql, database, replication, database-replication, failover

I have a master-master mysql setup based on a master-slave relationship for replication purpose. I have managed to get the replication portion working and was investigating the failover portion whereby a slave will become a master (should the original master went down) based on manual intervention.

However, I am unable to 'Redirect Writes to New Master After Relay Log is Applied'. I am attempting to do this via the connector/J. The connection string used in the application code is `String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://180.148.100.222,180.148.100.223:3306/dbName";`

The expected result should be when I start a new session via http://180.148.100.222:8080/index.html (client app) to initiate a WRITE operation, it will redirect to 180.148.100.223 (as 180.148.100.222 will fail at this instance) and carry out the write operation successfully.

However, I am unable to achieve the result. When I try to initiate such as order, the client app just remain at a loading status till it proceed to a timeout.

Thanks in advance - Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Same issue for me : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10929143/1047365

Answer (score 2):

By setting the parameter `failOverReadOnly=false` you can prevent the failover connection to be in read-only mode. Also use `com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver` or tell your jdbc connection url select the driver internaly by setting the url like `jdbc:mysql:replication://<your url...>`

In a test environment with two mysql database instances (Port 3306 and 3307) I used the following jdbc connection url:

```
jdbc:mysql:replication://address=(type=master)(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3306),address=(type=master)(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3307)/test?autoReconnect=true&amp;connectTimeout=50&amp;failOverReadOnly=false&amp;allowMasterDownConnections=true" />
```

For additional parameters see [Properties for Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

The configuration uses **load-balancing masters**. If the first master goes down, the second master will handle all traffic until the first master comes up again (and vice versa). I'm not a database expert, but I wouldn't recommend such a configuration for production use, because I guess your application's transaction is not aware of the database's internal replication status.

---

What you actually need is a **solution without load-balanced masters**. This can be done using a connection pool. I used the build in features of `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`, but it has one **disadvantage: the pool is created just once** and is available only until the first master goes down. There won't be a pool on the second master. Maybe this behavior could be influenced by extending BasicDataSource with own logic, I haven't fully tested it yet.

My recommendation is to restart your application (this creates a new connection pool) after you are done with maintenance. During maintenance, your application might become slower due to connections being created based on requests instead of being pulled from the pool, but you won't have any application down-time (..if your app is clustered).

Here's the code:

```
 <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"        
        value="jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master),address=(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3307)(type=master)/test?autoReconnect=true&amp;connectTimeout=5&amp;failOverReadOnly=false&amp;allowMasterDownConnections=true" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="myDBUser" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="myPassword" />
    <beans:property name="initialSize" value="10"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Note that there is no use of `ReplicationDriver`, the `BasicDataSource` handels the failover.

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Try to build your connection url like this in case of tcp connection:

```
jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=<IP address host 1>)(port=<your port>)(type=master),address=(protocol=tcp)(host=<IP address host 2>)(port=<your port>)(type=master)/<db_name>
```

Use `(protocol=tcp)`, or `(protocol=pipe)` for named pipes on Windows, and `(path=path_to_pipe)` for named pipes `(host=hostname)` for TCP

Make sure you are using MySQL Connector/J 5.1.27 or higher, see [Support for Mulitple-Master](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html). It should work when using IPv6 addresses. It (should) also works with IPv4 and direct all traffic to the first master. When the first master goes down, the connection is switched to the second master. However, I noticed that the failover-connection to the second master is suddenly read-only. I try to figure out why...

As an alternative, you could also configure a loadbalanced connection, see [this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/carriergrademysql/entry/how_to_use_jdbc_connector).

Michael